# How to make a page always fit the frame while the main window is being resized? WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, responsive

I have a MainWindow with 3 grid columns and a frame inside the 2° and 3° column, both frames contains pages.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window [the usual stuff]
    Title="p" Height="1080" Width="1920" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="ThreeDBorderWindow" Background="White" WindowState="Maximized">
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="35*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="55*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Background="DarkGreen">

        <Button x:Name="ControlButton" Content="Control" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="39,214,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="116" Height="42" Click="ControlButton_Click"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Background="DarkSalmon">
        <Frame x:Name="MainFrame" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Column="2" Background="DarkTurquoise">
        <Frame x:Name="ChartFrame" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

I've set the grid columns as number* so that it resizes automatically when the window is being resized. So I know the first frame size is 35% of all width of the window, how do I set the same thing for the page that the frame hosts.

Page.xaml

```
<Page [usual stuff]
  d:DesignHeight="1049" d:DesignWidth="669"
  Title="FirstPage">

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Column="0">
        <Button x:Name="LangButton" Content="English" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="715,26,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="LangButton_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

The width and height of the page are set just because I don't what to put there. I would like that what's in my page will resize to fit the frame dimension while the MainWindow is being resized.

Comment: Remove the margins of the Button and the ColumnDefinition? I guess you want the Button to fill the entire frame?

Comment: @mm8 I want to keep my button in the middle of the page. I want my page to react to being resized like the frame is reacting. If I launch the application in 1920x1080 and resize it, the frame will always take up 35% of the total width, I can't find a way to let the page do the same. (I have a listview and other stuff in the page, for simplicity here I just showed a button).

Comment: "For simplicity"? It's not very simple for someone to know what you mean unless you provide a repo of your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. In your current example, the Button in the Page should fill 35% of the total width just as expected.